# JSON data to array of specific type [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to turn JSON data to Recipe[].

This is the response from the API:

```
{
    "criteria": {
        "requirePictures": true,
        "q": null,
        "allowedIngredient": null,
        "excludedIngredient": null
    },
    "matches": [
        {
            "imageUrlsBySize": {
                "90": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/8H_kR4fF6IE517FKDHGOyVHEgNmmCdhX_Yz2YfxIDJgCQoU_NJ-hw_FJ1jEolQPPAfoKuKMw4jYjJK512gTyfQ=s90-c"
            },
            "sourceDisplayName": "Mrs. Happy Homemaker",
            "ingredients": [
                "frozen meatballs",
                "pasta sauce",
                "shredded mozzarella cheese",
                "shredded parmesan cheese",
                "Italian seasoning"
            ],
            "id": "Meatball-Parmesan-Casserole-2626493",
            "smallImageUrls": [
                "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/3dbNmfS4BI-7CUsm2WYE8l7-90CNi3rQPUkO5EMc0gts_MBUAVZlTngm-9VHshp9toXl73RKwiUs9JQCpx6RoQ=s90"
            ],
            "recipeName": "Meatball Parmesan Casserole",
            "totalTimeInSeconds": 900,
            "attributes": {
                "course": [
                    "Main Dishes"
                ]
            },
            "flavors": null,
            "rating": 4
        }
    ],
    "facetCounts": {},
    "totalMatchCount": 1228808,
    "attribution": {
        "html": "Recipe search powered by <a href='http://www.yummly.co/recipes'><img alt='Yummly' src='https://static.yummly.co/api-logo.png'/></a>",
        "url": "http://www.yummly.co/recipes/",
        "text": "Recipe search powered by Yummly",
        "logo": "https://static.yummly.co/api-logo.png"
    }
}
```

This is me trying to solve it with map operator.

```
  list(): Observable<Recipe[]> {
    return this.http.get('url').pipe(
      map(data =>
        data.matches.map((item: any) =>
          new Recipe({
            name: item.recipeName
          })
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

But it says that "matches does not exist on type Object". Am I missing something? How can I access "matches" array so I can create instances of Recipe for an array? Should I even use the map operator or do it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

```
  list(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('url').pipe(
      map(data =>
        data.matches.map((item: any) =>
          new Recipe({
            name: item.recipeName
          })
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

Or

```
list(): Observable<Recipe> {
    return this.http.get('url').pipe(
      map(data =>
        data.matches.map((item: any) =>
          new Recipe({
            name: item.recipeName
          })
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

Try doing one of this, as you are getting one json object from url and in observables you are giving array of object.

Comment: Made no difference. Still saying that matches does not exist on type 'Object'.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it by replacing it with:

```
  list(): Observable<Recipe[]> {
    return this.http.get('url').pipe(
      map((data: any) =>
        data.matches.map((item: any) =>
          new Recipe({
            name: item.recipeName
          })
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

data --> (data: any)